# Why is the forward slash mandatory when forwarding from servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

When using a request dispatcher in a servlet to forward to a JSP why must the JSP be denoted with a forward slash like the following-:

```
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/foo.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

If I use it without the forward slash I get an exception in Tomcat.

But when I use request dispatcher for redirecting to servlets then I can omit the forward slash. The below code fragment works fine provided there is a servlet mapped to the url pattern-:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("bar").forward(request, response);
```

I know that the `/` means the root of the web-app but why isn't it required for servlets but only for JSPs ? Servlets also belong to a particular web-app.

Comment: slash indicates a root folder, and it isn't required for jsp

Comment: Could you share your servlet mapping that doesn't require the /?

Comment: It maybe because, your JSP in at the root folder, while your servlet url is relative to current servlet url like `path/currentUrl`->`path/bar`

Comment: @JohnAment `@WebServlet("/bar")` This is what I used. And I am getting a Tomcat exception when I don't use the slash with the JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the servlet objects are running at the same place in container but jsp goes to different place.

SERVLET LOCATION AFTER DEPLOYEMENT
You will find all the servlets here
apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\Test\WEB-INF\classes\com\it\servlet

MainController.class

ABC.class

JSP LOCATION AFTER DEPLOYEMENT

apache-tomcat-7.0.55\work\Catalina\localhost\Test\org\apache\jsp

apiTester_jsp.class

Answer (score 2):

Your are mistaken to believe that the forward slash means root of the web app.  It can sometimes mean that, but not always.

The forward slash '/' character is used in JSPs within links eg:

```
<a href="/foo/stuff.htm">Stuff page</a>
```

and in servlets by the `RequestDispatcher.forward()` and `HTTPResponse.sendRedirect()` methods for URL redirections.

It only has an effect when applied at the **beginning** of your redirection URL.

Here are the rules for how it is interpreted behind the scenes by the your application server:

1. First of all: Please be aware that the redirection address is always CASE SENSITIVE -even in the domain segment of your redirection-URL. See my comments in example code below to see an illustration of this through examples of what will work and what will fail.
2. If the redirection commences with 'http://', the ABSOLUTE path as specified, will be used in the redirection.

   **Otherwise** your redirection URL will be applied as a **relative** URL.
3. If the redirection URL commences with a forward slash character '/', your application server is instructed to construct a URL RELATIVE to the web container!

   For example: relative to `localhost:8080`

   So the command...

   `response.sendRedirect("/foo/stuff.htm")`

   from inside a servlet, or

   `<a href="/foo/stuff.htm">Stuff page</a>`

   from inside a JSP, will take you to

   [localhost:8080/foo/stuff.htm](http://localhost:8080/foo/stuff.htm).
4. The ABSENCE of a forward slash at the beginning of your redirection-url (together with the absence of a protocol signature) will instruct the app server to construct its url relative to the ORIGINAL REQUESTED URL!  That is, the URL typed into the browser by a user at the client-side.

   It is important to be aware that this constructed URL is **neither**

   - relative to the domain

     **nor**
   - relative to the web container!

   Once again: the url constructed by the application server will be *relative to the original url requested by the client!*

   So for example:  if a client provides the URL

   http://www.example.com/level1/level2/stuff.htm

   then the command...
    `response.sendRedirect("foo/stuff.htm")` 
   from within a servlet or,
   `<a href="foo/stuff.htm">Stuff page</a>` 
   from within a JSP, will redirect you to 
   http://www.example.com/level1/level2/foo/stuff.htm

   // WILL NOT WORK!  Reason: Case sensitivity.
   response.sendRedirect("/teluskolearnings/login.jsp");

   // WILL WORK!  Reason: Case sensitivity.
   response.sendRedirect("/TeluskoLearnings/login.jsp");

   // Will redirect to localhost:8080/login.jsp as the forward slash tells app
   // server to build the url RELATIVE TO THE APP SERVER.
   // So you will be pointed to 'http://localhost:8080/login.jsp'.
   // This is not what we want.
   response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");

   // Will redirect to localhost:8080/TeluskoLearnings/login.jsp
   // as the ABSENCE of forward slash tells app server to build the url
   // RELATIVE TO THE URL!
   // So you will be pointed to
   // 'http://localhost:8080/TeluskoLearnings/login.jsp'.
   // This IS what we want.
   response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

   // Will redirect to localhost:8080/TeluskoLearnings/foo/login.jsp 
   // (you can see the redirection in the address bar, even if you get a
   // 404 - page not found) as the ABSENCE of forward slash (at the start) tells
   // app server to build the URL RELATIVE TO THE REQUESTED URL!
   // This also means that if the user entered
   // 'http://localhost:8080/TeluskoLearnings/level1/level2/stuff"'
   // he will be pointed to
   // 'http://localhost:8080/TeluskoLearnings/level1/level2/foo/login.jsp'
   // (provided of course, that "/level1/level2/stuff" is captured inside the
   // urlPatterns parameter of the @WebServlet() annotation).
   response.sendRedirect("foo/login.jsp");

SEE:  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch04s27.html

Comment: I want to elaborate on this part "response.sendRedirect("/foo/stuff.htm")" - the location string will be converted relative to the current request URI. In case request URI is "/myaddress/save", conversion result would be "/myaddress/foo/stuff.htm"